# Question closed asking for focus but comment says off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question [Coin change: minimize coins between payor and clerk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837149) was closed 5 days ago. The closure reason reads "This question needs to be more focused".

I don't see any way it can be given a tighter focus; I explain that I understand how to do the standard coin change; I at least imply I'm talking about the specific set of US coins and bills; and I explain how my question is different than other coin change problems.

The only comment left for me at the time of closure does not mention focus at all. It instead seems to imply that asking this question is off-topic. If that's the case, then why was the closure reason different?

In the last five days I have actually reached a solution on my own, that I would post if the question were reopened.

Comment: Your asking for an algorithm, right?

Comment: Yes.  Would it be advisable to just add that wording to my question?  *now added*  Or add my existing code? *not yet added*  (Thank you for retagging this meta question)

Comment: Well, it does help, yes. There also is an [tag:algorithm] tag, I would add that as well. Having a starting point and/or a specific step where you're stuck is often better. At the moment your question on main reads as an *this is my requirements list / task assignment, anyone else please do the heavy lifting*. Instead on SO it is better to share / make clear what you do know/what works so users can take that as a starting point instead of having to assume you know nothing and you did nothing yet. Sharing what you researched already is also advisable.

Comment: code added. I'm not sure how to "make clear what I do know / what works" in this case, since in fact I now have a solution.

Comment: *If that's the case, then why was the closure reason different?* @RossPresser I think they weren't suggesting a different close reason as much as they weren't being specific. The closure dialog no longer labels specific close reasons as off-topic. There's just the standard ones and the community specific ones.

Comment: Note that as a result of the history of close reasons, "needs more focus" is sometimes erroneously used when "needs more details" would be appropriate. The latter line of reasoning *might* apply since you already present an partial algorithm (prefer the smaller payment) but do not clarify what stops you from using that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very hard to keep a *"What is the code/solution for X?"* question open on Stack Overflow. It is also hard to keep a problem that does not look like having any practical value to be open.

I see these two reasons apply to the post - it does not show any relevant research and looks like absolutely a non-practical problem one is doing for their personal entertainment.

It is debatable if such questions are really off-topic for Stack Overflow (generally "how-to" should be on topic), but currently such questions are pretty much guaranteed to be closed as either "need more focus" or "need more details". Both reasons are pretty much equally likely to be used unrelated to the question itself.

Indeed the edited question is better than many questions falling into the same category - you did show that a similar-looking problem can be solved (the original version lacked that, contributing to closure). Unfortunately it is mostly useless for an algorithmic question - one needs to show that ideas from the similar problem actually apply to one in the question. That step alone is non-trivial - changing from a simple sum of positive numbers (which is an awesome monotonous function) to the sum of positive and negative numbers likely significantly impacts available approaches.

It could have helped to show one of several obvious brute-force solutions and explain how you would like to improve them. I.e.

- "I tried to just brute-force by getting all possible results using all possible combinations of 1, 2, 3... coins  stopping at as soon as I got the desired sum. This looks really bad because ... and I'd like to make it ... a {O(number of possible coins)} solution."
- just trying all possible combinations of coins where each nomination is used 0-{count of precise sum problem} times...

Basically any attempt to solve the problem asked in the question would make the question far less likely to get closed.

There is a subclass of such questions that are less likely to get closed - the ones where an obvious solution turns out to be wrong after a short consideration. This type of questions quickly turn into hot network questions or at the very least get upvoted - ["why code on sorted array is faster"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) is an example of such a problem - you open it and go though "totally stupid, they simply lie" to "what, that's happening... I know it is X..." ending at "that's unbelievable - none of ideas I come up in the last 5 minutes explain it +10".

Unfortunately for your question it did not turn out to be the case either - as with any problem with a relatively small number of items, brute-force trying all combinations is *an obvious solution* - and emotions instead go "that's maybe interesting puzzle" to "did not try much, copy-pasted some unrelated code" to "there is an obvious solution... the OP can't be asking for one - what are they  asking for then?".

If you got working code as an answer - posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) may be a better option than Stack Overflow  - unless this particular question for some unlikely reason will become HNQ you probably will not get much feedback on the solution.

Note that to get a proper solution such algorithm questions likely need to be asked on one of more research-oriented computer science sites on Stack Exchange... Generally any working solution without a theoretical reasoning would be enough on Stack Overflow, which clearly is not really a useful answer to such a problem.

Comment: For some additional context: my achieved solution was not negative numbers, but treating the two halves of the exchange separately: Instead of solving $1.98, solve $2.00 and then solve $0.02, and sum the coin count.  Brute force this from $0 overpayment to double the bill amount and find the solution(s) with the fewest coins.